# what do i keep getting ClassCastExpection

Tags: java, android, exception

When ever i try running my code i keep getting this error in logcat

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams

i'm trying to get layout parameter so i can modify it dynamically.

here is the java code

```
    TableRow k1 = (TableRow)main.getChildAt(main.getChildCount()-1);
    TableRow.LayoutParams k2 = (TableRow.LayoutParams)k1.getLayoutParams();
    Log.e(TAG, "---------Displaying k2- \t" + k2);
```

main represent the `TableLayout` that already exists
here is the xml file

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/abit_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="32dp">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="13dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ability"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ability"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/abil"
                    android:layout_width="147dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/ability"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mastery"
                    android:layout_width="82dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/master"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

can someone explain me what this error mean and how to solve it??
any help will be appreciated

Comment: it's suppose to be k1, my bad

Comment: A `View`'s `LayoutParams` will be its parent's type, not its own. Your `TableRow`s are inside a `TableLayout`, so they will have `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, not `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Comment: @MikeM. so is there any way i can  get the `TableRow.LayoutParams`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The `TextView`s in your layout will have `TableRow.LayoutParams`, since they are inside `TableRow`s. However, the `TableRow`s themselves will have `TableLayout.LayoutParams`, as mentioned. `LayoutParams` are information for the parent to lay out its children. That's why the children will have the parent's `LayoutParams` type.

Comment: i just want to modify the `TableRow` k1

Comment: If you mean you want to modify `k1`'s `LayoutParams`, then just use `TableLayout.LayoutParams` there, instead of `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Comment: wouldn't that modify other row's as well??

Comment: Nope. Each `TableRow` will have its own separate instance of `TableLayout.LayoutParams` on it. The `LayoutParams` instances don't directly belong to the parent. They're just its type, so the parent knows how to read them correctly. They actually belong to each individual child. They're just little packets of information that tells the parent how it should lay out a given child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the exception says , `k1.getLayoutParams()` will return `TableLayout.LayoutParams` not `TableRow.LayoutParams`

change your code to this :

```
TableRow k1 = (TableRow)main.getChildAt(main.getChildCount()-1);
TableLayout.LayoutParams k2 = (TableLayout.LayoutParams)k1.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: but i don't want to modify the `TableLayout` but `TableRow`